# How to delete a specific member out of a JSON with python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I tried different ways, but nothing works pretty much.
I would like to delete a specific member out of the JSON when he leaves the server.
Intents are on and the rest of the code works perfectly fine. Any tips?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    del users[member.id]

    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

As example I would like to remove "801014207230640168" from the JSON

```
{"801014207230640168": {"xp": 11, "level": 1, "last_message": 1614718416.40123, "name": "BlackF00xTest"}}
```

Comment: `users.pop(str(member.id), None)` is what you are looking for

Comment: You can use `del dict[key]` just fine. Did you print users before and after the del, and also member.id to check they were all what you expected? You can obviously try this with a simple example in the Python REPL and it works fine.

Comment: member.id is and integer so you should convert it del users[str(member.id)]